# Ext.js dipatch how to?

Tags: extjs

I have a question regarding using **Ext.dispatch** in MVC. The scenario is simple, how about for one event, I want to dispatch into two separate controller? should i duplicate ext.dispatch or ext.dispatch can receive any type of array or object for controller property?

e.g:

```
Ext.dispatch({ controller: ['cont1', 'cont2'], action: ['show', 'create']})
```

How should I do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to execute two different Ext.dispatch calls.

Comment: I'll take this answer for now.